# Remove S from "S9.98" but not from "Sep" in string "S9.98 Sep" using Regex

Tags: regex, c#-4.0

From the following string "test S9.98 Sep", i want to remove the S in front of the numbers. But not from "test" or "Sep" using RegEx.

I have tried this

```
string result = Regex.Replace("test S9.98 Sep", "S(?!^Sep$)", "", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

or

```
string result = Regex.Replace("test S9.98 Sep", "[S]", "", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

But I get "tet 9.98 ep"

Comment: Would a simple `S(?=\d)` work ?

Comment: `(S)[0-9]` would even work right?

Comment: @sln yes, S(?=\d) would work too.

Comment: @Thomas No, (S)[0-9] would not work.

Comment: @AlexMendez https://regex101.com/r/aA6yE0/1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a lookahead regex like this:

```
string result = Regex.Replace("test S9.98 Sep", @"S(?=\d+(?:\.\d+)?)", "", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

`S(?=\d+(?:\.\d+)?)` is positive lookahead that will match letter `S` only if it is immediately followed by an integer or decimal number.

**Reference:** [Lookahead and Lookbehind Zero-Length Assertions](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)

Comment: I have marked this as the answer as it was the first correct answer plus a bonus reference of lookahead. Thank you all.

Comment: But so many unnecessary things to check inside the lookahead.

Answer (score 2):

Your lookahead is pretty close. The only problem is that your lookahead was looking for `Sep` again, while `S` has already been matched:

```
string result = Regex.Replace("test S9.98 Sep", "\\bS(?!ep(\\b|$))", "", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

[Demo](http://ideone.com/cPVgRd)

Comment: You answer returns "tet 9.98 Sep" removeing the s from "test"

Comment: @AlexMendez Oops, forgot to double my slashes. I updated the demo as well.

Comment: Now id does not remove the S from the numbers "test S9.98 Sep"

Comment: @AlexMendez Yes it does. Did you click the demo?

Comment: @dasblinkelnight Yes, you are right. On the windows form i am using i paste the expression, but i do not need to escape it there.

Answer (score 2):

Use a positive look ahead after `S` and a word boundary before it.

```
string result = Regex.Replace("test S9.98 Sep", @"\bS(?=\d)", "", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

The `(?=\d)` positive lookahead will allow matching `S` before a digit (not including the digit in the match). The word boundary will require `S` to appear after a nonword char (or start of a string).